# Python create Buttons and Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been googling about this problem and couldn't find any good websites....
I want to create buttons and entry widget looks like:

> [A] [B] [C] [D] [E] [F]
>
> [ENTRYWIDGET HERE]   [OK]

My code looks like:

> class Controller(Frame):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self,parent):
>     Frame.__init__(self, parent)
>     self.parent = parent
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "A")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "B")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "C")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "D")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "E")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>     self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "F")
>     self.button1.pack(side = TOP)
>
>     self.myentrybox = Entry(parent, width = 50)
>     self.myentrybox.pack(side = LEFT)
>     self.button = Button(parent, text = "OK")
>     self.button.pack(side = RIGHT )
> ```

And this looks completely different with what i'm trying to create..

Any feedbacks would be so grateful thanks.

Comment: you should put what library your using ... I dont think its wx...

Comment: You need use one of the [layout or geometry managers](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/layout-mgt.html) and tell it how to arrange your widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put your buttons into *another* `Frame`.

---

**Example:**

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class Controller(Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        buttons = Frame(parent)
        buttons.pack(side=TOP)
        for letter in 'ABCDEF':
            Button(buttons, text=letter).pack(side=LEFT)

        Entry(parent, width=50).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(parent, text='OK').pack(side=RIGHT)

root = Tk()
app = Controller(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**Edit to answer your comments**

If you want to stick with `for` loop for creating the buttons, a good way to apply the event handler is to create a mapping of `button` <=> `function to call` using a `dict`:

```
    handler = {'A': function_A,
               'B': function_FooBar,
               'C': function_SomeThing}

    for letter, func in ((k, handler[k]) for k in sorted(handler)):
        Button(buttons, text=letter, command=func, width=10).pack(side=LEFT)
```

This way, it's easily extendable. If you don't care about the order of the buttons, you can just use

```
for letter, func in handler.items():
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. In this case, how do I define the commands for each button?

Comment: @JuM It depends. What should those `Buttons` do? Are they somehow related to each other, e.g. call the some method with another parameter or something like this? Are they really named `A`...`F`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use another layout manager, e.g. using the [`grid()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/layout-mgt.html) method, which is a bit more expressive.

```
def __init__(self,parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.grid()
    # create buttons in row 1
    for i, c in enumerate("ABCDEF"):
        self.button = Button(parent, text=c)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=i+1)
    # create textfield and 'ok' in row 2    
    self.myentrybox = Entry(parent, width = 50)
    self.myentrybox.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=6)
    self.button = Button(parent, text = "OK")
    self.button.grid(row=2, column=7)
```